# What Parts of English Grammar Can Be Mapped To German?

Tags: english-to-german

I'm taking on learning German and I've started by creating a map of what I believe are the core grammar components of English

### Verbs

### Nouns (Pronouns)

### Conjugation (Infinitive, Tense [Past, Present, Future], Possession)

### Adjectives

### Preposition

### Adverbs

### Conjunctions

### Articles (Definite, Indefinite)

(Feel free to call out anything you might be missing in the above)

As I learn German would it be appropriate to map my understanding of German to these components directly? If not, what parts of what I listed above would be inappropriate to map to German?

Comment: do you mean 'progressive' instead of 'possession' in the tenses line? That said, I'm not sure what you mean with mapping. On a broader scale all these things do exist, though the tenses are different and differently used. However that does not mean you can map one sentence 1:1 with the same grammar to the other language and expect it to make sense or keep the semantic meaning. It's not even unambiguous. "Ich gehe nach hause" -> I go home / I'm going home (context dependent). You must do that -> Du musst das tun. You must not do that -> Du darfst das nicht tun. etc etc

Comment: I did mean possession like "That's Mike's".

By mapping I mean can I take a concept in German and connect it directly to a topic here.

From your point about 1:1 I was not expecting structure to map directly (like ordering of words), but rather the concepts (or lack there of), in terms of equivalency. For example English has no male/female words, so that wouldn't be something anything could be mapped to in languages that do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether I fully understand your question, but as English is a Germanic language (albeit one that has had some unusual things happen to it), there are many structural similarities and you can compare along the features that you list. Sometimes, that comparison will bring up major differences, but think you will find little that is completely alien to you as an English speaker. (Well, you mention grammatical gender already in a comment to the question. Yes, we have that, and no, it is not only two genders.)

For example, the German tenses structurally correspond to English tenses (no progressive aspect, though), but their usage is different.

German adjectives are declined.

German has a full case system with four cases while English has merged two of the cases and marks case almost exclusively in pronouns.

Comment: Thanks. I have found that most learning resources (at least from my personal attempts) focus on words and sentences but not really the underlying grammar structure as a whole and how things fit into it. My goal is create the overall structure map of German grammar and then be able to both compare/differentiate from English and also have a place to put things as I learn them in German

Comment: @Aggressor, I understand. I also like old-fashioned books that start with an overview of the grammar before teaching me simple sentences.

Comment: In terms of parts of speech, yes, German and English are about the same. But even a totally unrelated languages like Japanese has nouns, verbs and adjectives. When you start getting into more detail, for example word order, cases, and separable verbs, German and English are very different. In my experience trying to leverage English to learn German is very unreliable; half the time it will lead to more confusion than understanding.

Comment: @RDBury, sure, but, there are languages that don't have those things. For example, Chinese doesn't really have adjectives, or at least it doesn't make a grammatical distinction between adjectives and verbs.

Comment: What makes you think that could be done at all, let alone usefully listed here rather than in a full-length text book? It's true that once-upon-a-time English and German were pretty-much the same and it's also true that in modern English, once-upon-a-time generally refers to fairy tales. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick answer for things relevant to a person on B1 to B2 level.

In English, for describing possesion, there are two concepts: Possesive pronouns and Possesive Artikels eg: (mine, my). However, in German, this gets combined into one stem (mein) with different declensions in masculine and neutral case.

Then there are verb moods, for speaking about certain special situation in German like that of irreality or of reported speech, there are a pair of different verb moods named Konjunktiv-1 and Konjunktiv-2. For each of these verb moods, it comes with their own tenses like Konjunkitiv-2 present , past etc.

For tenses, it is a bit more technical and I think it's better to learn as you go.

Another thing is that there is a bit of overlap in the reflexive pronoun and personal pronoun chart. So, it may lead to a bit of confusion to decide which is which.

Other big similarties are mentioned by Carten S already.